# .Net XML Serializer and matrix

Tags: c#, serialization, c++-cli, xmlserializer

I have a C++/CLI code wrapped and used in C# project.
I have a class in the C++/CLI code which contains a matrix declared as follows:

```
array<double, 2>^   S_to_Box_Matrix;
S_to_Box_Matrix = gcnew array<double, 2>(4, 4);
```

it seems that this variable is not serializable. 
How to make it serializable? 
If not possible then How to exclude it from being serialized (which C++/CLI keyword and what libraries to import)
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`XmlSerializer` does not support 2d arrays.  The most straightforward way to work around this is to modify your c++/cli class as follows:

- Mark the 2d array with [`[XmlIgnore]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- Introduce a proxy property that converts the 2d array from and to a jagged array.
- Mark the jagged array property with [`[XmlArray]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlarrayattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

For instance:

```
#using <System.Xml.dll>

public ref class Array2DTestClass
{
public:
    [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlIgnore]
    array<double, 2> ^S_to_Box_Matrix;

    [System::Xml::Serialization::XmlArray("S_to_Box_Matrix")]
    property array<array<double> ^>^  S_to_Box_Matrix_Serializable {
        array<array<double> ^>^  get();
        System::Void set(array<array<double> ^>^  value);
    }
};
```

With implementations

```
array<array<double> ^>^  Array2DTestClass::S_to_Box_Matrix_Serializable::get() {
    return ArrayExtensions::ToJaggedArray(this->S_to_Box_Matrix);
}

System::Void Array2DTestClass::S_to_Box_Matrix_Serializable::set(array<array<double> ^>^  value) {
    this->S_to_Box_Matrix = ArrayExtensions::To2DArray(value);
}
```

Using the helper methods:

```
public ref class ArrayExtensions abstract sealed {
    public:
        generic<typename T> static array<array<T>^> ^ToJaggedArray(array<T, 2> ^input)
        {
            if (input == nullptr)
                return nullptr;
            int nRow = input->GetLength(0);
            int nCol = input->GetLength(1);
            array<array<T>^> ^output = gcnew array<array<T>^>(nRow);
            for (int iRow = 0; iRow < nRow; iRow++)
            {
                output[iRow] = gcnew array<T>(nCol);
                for (int iCol = 0; iCol < nCol; iCol++)
                    output[iRow][iCol] = input[iRow, iCol];
            }
            return output;
        }

        generic<typename T> static array<T, 2> ^To2DArray(array<array<T> ^>^input)
        {
            if (input == nullptr)
                return nullptr;
            int nRow = input->Length;
            int nCol = 0;
            for (int iRow = 0; iRow < nRow; iRow++)
                if (input[iRow] != nullptr)
                    nCol = Math::Max(nCol, input[iRow]->Length);
            array<T, 2> ^ output = gcnew array<T, 2>(nRow, nCol);
            for (int iRow = 0; iRow < nRow; iRow++)
                if (input[iRow] != nullptr)
                    for (int iCol = 0; iCol < input[iRow]->Length; iCol++)
                        output[iRow, iCol] = input[iRow][iCol];
            return output;
        }
};
```

Doing so, I get XML that looks like:

> ```
> <Array2DTestClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
>     <S_to_Box_Matrix>
>         <ArrayOfDouble>
>             <double>0</double>
>             <double>1</double>
>             <double>2</double>
>         </ArrayOfDouble>
>         <ArrayOfDouble>
>             <double>3</double>
>             <double>4</double>
>             <double>5</double>
>         </ArrayOfDouble>
>     </S_to_Box_Matrix>
> </Array2DTestClass>
> ```

Comment: They both should work.  Given an attribute `FooAttribute`, it can be applied as `[FooAttribute]` or just `[Foo]` with the `-Attribute` suffix omitted.  See http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/ccli-attributes/199901816